# Powershell: Exporting AD MachineName/UserName/IPv4Address to a single *.csv

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, windows-10

I have an `OU` that is full of default-named machines. The problem is these machines have already been sent out through 50+ sites and I don't know who has what. The below code, has done the job but I have to merge the two CSV's which isn't all that complicated but it's a step that I don't think I **have** to have.

Here is my current code (working with two CSV's):

```
###Creates temp-function to get the current user logged into machine###

function Get-LoggedOnUser {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1 })]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    foreach ($comp in $ComputerName) {
        $output = @{ 'ComputerName' = $comp }
        $output.UserName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $comp).UserName
        [PSCustomObject]$output
    }
}

###Change the -SearchBase parameters to the appropriate container.#######

$computer = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=IMAGE,OU=WORKSTATIONS,DC=AD,DC=XXX,DC=US" |
    Sort-Object Name

$allinfo = @()
foreach ($machine in $computer.Name) {
    $Array = "" | Select-Object Machine
    $array.Machine = $machine
    Get-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $machine |
        Export-Csv "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\loggedOnUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append

    Get-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $machine |
        Test-Connection -Count 1 |
        Select-Object @{ n = "Machine"; e = { $_.Address } }, Ipv4Address |
        Export-Csv "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\ips.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

I have edited the code with `XXX` in some places, I'm not questioning those areas. I can't seem to get the end of the code to merge into one CSV.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding IP address to your function object like this:

```
function Get-LoggedOnUser {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1})]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    foreach ($comp in $ComputerName) {
        $output = @{ 'ComputerName' = $comp }
        $output.UserName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $comp).UserName
        $output.Ipv4Address = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $machine -Count 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Ipv4Address)
        [PSCustomObject]$output
    }
}

###Change the -SearchBase parameters to the appropriate container.#######

$computer = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=IMAGE,OU=WORKSTATIONS,DC=AD,DC=XXX,DC=US" |
Sort-Object Name

$allinfo = @()
foreach ($machine in $computer.Name) {
    $Array = "" | Select-Object Machine
    $array.Machine = $machine

Get-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $machine | Export-Csv "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\\AllInOne.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was missing. I had tried creating a variable, in the wrong location!